# Document is undefined in index.js (frontail streaming of logs)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have found a library on npm that streams the logs into the browser called frontail ([GitHub Frontail](https://github.com/mthenw/frontail/), [Npm Frontail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/frontail)). My objective is to add a pause button, that pauses the generation of the logs. When that button is pressed again, it loads all the missing logs and works as usual. I am faimiliar with Node.js, CSS and HTML. I have noticed that they use bootstrap, so adding a pause button was relatively easy (in index.html in the web/assets):

```
<div class="navbar-nav">
     <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#" id="pause">Pause/Continue</a>
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Stop</a>
     <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Start</a>
</div>
```

just after:

```
<span class="navbar-brand" href="#">tail -F __TITLE__</span>
```

I have also found a listener that listens to the new lines being written to the log file in index.js:

```
 tailer.on('line', (line) => {
        filesSocket.emit('line', line);
  });
```

I have amended it a bit to suit my needs (please note that this is precisely where the code fails to work. It tells me that **document is not defined**, I tried **window.document**, that is also not defined).

```
 tailer.on('line', (line) => {
    var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
    if(!pauseButton.classList.contains('paused')) {
        filesSocket.emit('line', line);
    }
  });
```

I then created a .js file in the web/assets called button-config.js, that simply adds the "paused" class to my pause button, when the button is clicked, and removes it when it is clicked again:

```
function pauseClassToggle() {
        var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
        pauseButton.classList.toggle("paused");
}
```

and included it in the index.html file like so (last line):

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/tinycon.min.js"></script>
<script src="/ansi_up.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = new io.connect('/' + '__NAMESPACE__');

        window.load = App.init({
            socket: socket,
            container: document.getElementsByClassName('log')[0],
            filterInput: document.getElementsByClassName('query')[0],
            topbar: document.getElementsByClassName('topbar')[0],
            body: document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
        });
</script>
<script src="/button-config.js"></script>
```

One remaining thing is to add this function to addClick property when pause button is clicked. But no point of doing that because document is not defined in the scope of the index.js file, and I cannot understand how to circumvent that problem. Would appreciate your help.

Thanks

**P.S.**

Here is the error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/frontail/index.js:141
    var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
                      ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Tail.tailer.on (/usr/lib/node_modules/frontail/index.js:141:23)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Tail.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at LineStream.Tail.byline.on (/usr/lib/node_modules/frontail/lib/tail.js:39:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at LineStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at LineStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at LineStream.Transform.push (_stream_transform.js:147:32)
```

Comment: `document` runs on the client side, `tailer` looks like it runs on your server side.

Comment: you'll have to send something to the client.